# Facebook page access token validity length

Tags: php, facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have worked out how to get a facebook page access token and post to the page's wall. I would like to know if the facebook page access token expires and if so after how long? Also If it does expire what can i do to prolong it validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page access tokens don’t expire by default – but they will go invalid if the user under which they were obtained changes his password.

This is only true if you get a long-lived access token for the page admin before requesting the page's access_token from the API, otherwise it expires along with the user's access_token - see Scenario 5 on

Comment: This is only true if you get a long-lived access token for the page admin before requesting the page's `access_token` from the API, otherwise it expires along with the user's access_token - see Scenario 5 on https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/